# Amateur voice recording for a game

Tags: audio-recording, sound-effects, sound-effects-recording, audacity

I have developed a small card game. It is about geometrical shapes for educational purposes.

I have managed to create some amateur sounds which are not so good, using embeded laptop mic/headphones mic and Audacity. The result is kind of ok but it is mumbling i.e bad quality.

I don't have proper cache to pay somebody to record proper sound effects so this means I have to record something by myself.

What is the best way or which tools should I use to record amateur sound effects with the best quality possible?

I would like to hear your experiences?

Bassically I have words like: Triangle, Square, Rhombus, Trapezium etc...

Comment: Or I just continue using the same tools untill recording is perfect? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording good sounding voice overs (Voices from people you do not see) is a very costly thing.

A very basic setup for great results is the microphone Studio Projects B1, combined with a cheap Presonus or M-Audio mic preamp. Then you only need a mobile vocal booth and thats it. Around 250-500 bucks total. And for indi games, its more than enough.

If that is too much then I would use a Retina Macbook Pro to record the voice over. Or lend one of your friends. I would try to place it in front of my open wardrobe then test different distances to the microphone. The retina macbook mics are really well designed and even Lady Gaga recorded some vocals on them :)

If you only have some 10 words, and don't mind a german accent I can record em next week in my Studio.

I hope i can help.

GL

Comment: I have Nexus 7 :). It records rather well :D

Comment: we may try something for start, like basic sounds, GUI sound effects, If you really like do it for free

Comment: I have some spare time on wedness Day then i try it!

Comment: Do you have a List of all the words you need? Then i Record them on the Weekend! Good Day!

Comment: I was busy developing another prototype of the game. It doesn't pull your attention. User just plays three or four levels and stops. So I wanted to add graphics but that increases file size, and also if I add 45 sounds :D But we can try for the sake of exploration :)

Comment: Sorry about 40 sounds, 35 for cards and maybe 5 for other GUI elements. Not sure how much time is needed?